# Set number of partitions and replicas by code

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My Spring app creates Kafka topics, uses @RetryableTopic, etc. All topics are created with default partition numbers (1) and replicas (1).

KafkaAdmin:

```
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, servers);
    props.put("sasl.jaas.config",
            "...."));
    props.put("security.protocol", "...");
    props.put("sasl.mechanism", "...");
    return new KafkaAdmin(props);
}
```

I found how to create a topic with a specified name:

```
public NewTopic createTopic() {
    return TopicBuilder.name(topicName)
            .partitions(2)
            .replicas(2)
            .build();
}
```

But I need these settings (partitions, replicas) to be applied to all topics created, regardless their names, i.e. not to specify topicName.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to configure default partitions and replica values for all topics on the API side.

On the other hand, you can only change the default replica value directly in the Kafka broker using this parameter: `default.replication.factor=2` or `KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=2` if you are using Kafka with docker. So all new topics with no replica specifications will have 2 by default.

If you want to learn more about it:

[Here you can see all available parameters for your Kafka broker](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/oala/1.3.6?topic=collection-configuring-apache-kafka-brokers)

[Here are all of those parameters if you are using docker](https://github.com/ches/docker-kafka/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thank you! Pls advise where shall I specify default.replication.factor=2?